# update query in wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

i want to update a row of a custom table in db in wordpress.
But any of them do not work.
I can not understand what is the problem!

I executed these query but can not see any result.

```
$wpdb->update('wp_job' , array('translated_text'  => '$persiantext','status'=> 1 ), array( 'lead_id' => '$this->sefaresh_id ', 'id' => '$this->job_id') );
    $queryy=("UPDATE wp_job SET status=%d,translated_text=%s  WHERE lead_id='$this->sefaresh_id'  and id='$this->job_id';");    
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($queryy,1,$persiantext));
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE
    wp_job SET translated_text ='$persiantext' WHERE WHERE lead_id='$this->sefaresh_id'  and id='$this->job_id'");
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this one**

```
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_job SET translated_text='$persiantext' WHERE lead_id=$this->sefaresh_id"));
```

Hope this will help!!

Comment: thank you so much but I get this error:Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\sahand\wp-content\plugins\job-view\chatModel.php on line 95 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\sahand\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1246